# Many to Many relation in JPA entities

Tags: jpa, many-to-many

I have 5 tables:

### User:

username (PK)

### Role:

role_id(PK)
role_name

### Permissions:

perm_id(PK)
perm_name

### User_role_rels:

ur_id(PK)
username(FK) -> user.username
role_id(FK) -> role.role_id

### Role_perm_rels:

rp_id(PK)
role_id(FK) -> role.role_id
perm_id(FK) -> Permissions.perm_id

When I create JPA entities for these five tables I get List of UserRoleRels in User entity, but I would need list of permissions for this user. So, there should be a 
List permList in User entity.

I am new to JPA and not sure how I can achieve this using annotations?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no direct relationship between `User` and `Permission`, it's correct that `User` doesn't have a `permList` collection property.

Assuming that your IDE has created correctly the entities according to your tables, you don't have `ManyToMany` annotations in your classes, but only `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne`. This makes a little cumbersome to fetch the permissions collection:

```
String userName = "";
User myUser = entityManager.find(User.class, userName);
for (UserRoleRels urr : myUser.getUserRoleRelsList()) {
    Role r = urr.getRole();
    for(RolePermRels rpr : r.getRolePermRelsList()) {
        Permission p = rpr.getPermission();
    }
}
```

---

If you don't have an extra property in the ManyToMany relation tables (in your case `User_role_rels` and `Role_perm_rels`), you can drop the PK field for both. This will let your IDE: (1) create simpler Entity classes, (2) avoid the creation of the Entity classes for the relation tables, (3) use the `ManyToMany` annotations. With that change, you'll be able to access the permissions more easily and in a more readable way:

```
String userName = "";
User myUser = entityManager.find(User.class, userName);
for (Role r : myUser.getRoleList()) {
    List<Permission> pl = r.getPermissionList();
}
```

Useful links: [EclipseLink UserGuide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Relationship_Mappings/Collection_Mappings/ManyToMany), [JPA Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany).